# Birt Master Footer - Set data dynamically not working eclipse 4.3.1 (Maximo 7.6.1.1 - BIRT)

Tags: footer, birt, maximo

I am using Maximo 7.6.1.1 and Birt (eclipse 4.3.1). The requirement is to add some page related text with a field from the report into the footer on each page, so I am attempting to update the master page footer. The master page is local, not extended.

I have tried to repeat this from 2013 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lw_k1qHY_gU&t=4s) without success.

So using page level variables as described by the link did not work - it appears that the page event for the variable I chose (when the variable is about to be updated on the page) did not seem to be getting invoked.

Has this possibly changed (since 2013) or does someone know of another work around?

I tried to add a number of data elements to the footer without success.
I did see that if I added a value to the footer element in the initialization event for the report, that we could see that but we never got any updates even though the field we wanted to use was updated as it is normally.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Maximo, but these page variables only work if BIRT is running in 2 steps: RunTask, then RenderTask. If the program is using the single-step RundAndRenderTask, page variables don't work. This behaviour has not changed with "newer" BIRT releases.